# How to implement Gradient Descent algorithm in C# using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, linear-regression, gradient-descent

The goal is to create a gradient descent algorithm for simple linear regression. There are plenty of solution with multiple line of codes. How can i avoid nested for loop from the given example?

```
double[] x = new double[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
double[] y = new double[] { 5, 7, 9, 12 };

double slope_current = 0;
double intercept_current = 0;
double slope_derivative = 0;
double intercept_derivative = 0;
double learningRate = 0.01;
int iterations = 1500;

for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < x.Length; j++)
    {
        double y_pred = (slope_current * x[j]) + intercept_current;
        intercept_derivative += (1.0 / x.Length) * (y_pred - y[j]);
        slope_derivative += (1.0 / x.Length) * (y_pred - y[j]) * x[j];
    }

    intercept_current = intercept_current - learningRate * intercept_derivative;
    slope_current = slope_current - learningRate * slope_derivative;
}
```

I would like to create a more compact version using LINQ.

Comment: I would ask - why? The code is more readable with the nested for loops. It would be even more readable if you refactored `(1.0 / x.Length) * (y_pred - y[j])` into a separate variable.

Comment: Yes, it would be more readable that way. But i was curious about a solution for LINQ fanatics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The for loop could be replaced by the `Sum` and `Zip` functions using LINQ.

```
double[] x = new double[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
double[] y = new double[] { 5, 7, 9, 12 };

double slope_current = 0;
double intercept_current = 0;
double learningRate = 0.01;
int iterations = 5000;

for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
{
    double intercept_derivative = (1.0 / x.Length) * x.Zip(y, (x_i, y_i) => (slope_current * x_i + intercept_current) - y_i).Sum();
    double slope_derivative = (1.0 / x.Length) * x.Zip(y, (x_i, y_i) => ((slope_current * x_i + intercept_current) - y_i) * x_i).Sum();

    slope_current = slope_current - learningRate * slope_derivative;
    intercept_current = intercept_current - learningRate * intercept_derivative;
}
```